# Visual Studio 2008 - Is there a way to set a breakpoint for when a class is accessed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, breakpoints

I don't really care which line in a class was hit. I just want to know when the class is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an instantiable class, put a break point in the constructor.  If it has static methods or properties, you would have to put a breakpoint in the first line of each method/property.  As far as I know, that's the only way to break when a class is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not realy how it works.*You dont access file(unless your app is reading from it X-P).*

**You access a class and its methods/properties/contructors.** These can be in different files all together (using the [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd%28VS.80%29.aspx) keyword), so that will make things difficult already.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you explain a little more, maybe then we can give a better answer.

Comment: I meant to say class and not file. Sometimes I want to know when a class is being accessed but I'm not sure where to put the breakpoint. I'm looking for the behavior you would get if you were allowed to put a breakpoint on line one, usually where you'd find your using statements. That way I wouldn't have to place the breakpoint on any specific method, rather, every time a line of code within this class hits, it would break there.

Comment: Thats fine, you should be able to put the breakpoint on any given line within a method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to just putting a breakpoint in all instance constructors you could also create a static constructor and put a breakpoint in it if the class is static or if it has static methods. A static constructor is guaranteed to be executed before any static method in a class.